# XQuery where check Performance issue with SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, xquery, sqlxml, xquery-sql

I have one sql table with xml column which holds the value like below xml

```
<Security xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Dacl>
    <ACEInformation>
      <UserName>Authenticated Users</UserName>
      <Access>Allow</Access>
      <IsInherited>false</IsInherited>
      <ApplyTo>This object only</ApplyTo>
      <Permission>List Contents</Permission>
      <Permission>Read All Properties</Permission>
      <Permission>Read Permissions</Permission>
    </ACEInformation>
    <ACEInformation>
      <UserName>Administrator</UserName>
      <Access>Allow</Access>
      <IsInherited>false</IsInherited>
      <ApplyTo>This object only</ApplyTo>
      <Permission>Read All Properties</Permission>
      <Permission>Delete</Permission>
    </ACEInformation>
    <ACEInformation>
      <UserName>Admin2</UserName>
      <Access>Allow</Access>
      <IsInherited>false</IsInherited>
      <ApplyTo>This object only</ApplyTo>
      <Permission>Read All Properties</Permission>
      <Permission>Delete</Permission>
    </ACEInformation>
  </Dacl>
</Security>
```

Here my need is, I have to query all UserName values who are having values **Access: Allow** and **Permission: Delete**. For that, I am using following XQuery.

```
Select xmlColumn.query('for $item in (/Security/Dacl/ACEInformation[Access="Allow"][Permission="Delete"]/UserName) return concat($item,";")').value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)') from myTable
```

It returns the value : **Administrator;Admin2** for above xml. the query is working fine...but performance is very low it is taking 1 mins for 1000 rows.

Can you any one provide best xquery for this case?

Answer (score 1):

No real change in the xQuery but I changed the concat into a `for xml` concat instaed.

```
select (
       select A.X.value('(UserName/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)')+';'
       from T.xmlColumn.nodes('/Security/Dacl/ACEInformation[Access = "Allow" and Permission = "Delete"]') as A(X)
       for xml path(''), type
       ).value('text()[1]', 'nvarchar(max)')
from myTable as T
```

Comment: Thanks Mikael .it works well and performance issue is my pbm not in query

Comment: Hi Mikael, I have another question can you help me? please check this question entry---> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20188220/xquery-exists-check-in-select-sql-query

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's problem in XQuery, you can change it a little bit though (`[Access="Allow"][Permission="Delete"]` => `[Access="Allow" and Permission="Delete"]`).

On 1000 rows your query works pretty fast at SQL fiddle - see **<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/34a66/5)</kbd>**