# XQuery exists check in select sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xquery, sqlxml

I have one sql table with xml column which holds the value like below xml

```
<Security xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Dacl>
    <ACEInformation>
      <UserName>Authenticated Users</UserName>
      <Access>Allow</Access>
      <IsInherited>false</IsInherited>
      <ApplyTo>This object only</ApplyTo>
      <Permission>List Contents</Permission>
      <Permission>Read All Properties</Permission>
      <Permission>Read Permissions</Permission>
    </ACEInformation>
    <ACEInformation>
      <UserName>Administrator</UserName>
      <Access>Allow</Access>
      <IsInherited>false</IsInherited>
      <ApplyTo>This object only</ApplyTo>
      <Permission>Read All Properties</Permission>
      <Permission>Delete</Permission>
    </ACEInformation>
    <ACEInformation>
      <UserName>Admin2</UserName>
      <Access>Allow</Access>
      <IsInherited>false</IsInherited>
      <ApplyTo>This object only</ApplyTo>
      <Permission>Read All Properties</Permission>
      <Permission>Delete</Permission>
    </ACEInformation>
    <ACEInformation>
      <UserName>Admin2</UserName>
      <Access>Deny</Access>
      <IsInherited>false</IsInherited>
      <ApplyTo>This object only</ApplyTo>
      <Permission>Read All Properties</Permission>
      <Permission>Delete</Permission>
    </ACEInformation>
  </Dacl>
</Security>
```

Here my need is, I have to query all UserName values who are having values **Access: Allow**  and **Permission: Delete**. For that, I am using following XQuery.

```
select (
       select A.X.value('(UserName/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)')+';'
       from T.xmlColumn.nodes('/Security/Dacl/ACEInformation[Access = "Allow" and Permission = "Delete"]') as A(X)
       for xml path(''), type
       ).value('text()[1]', 'nvarchar(max)')
from myTable as T
```

It returns the value : **Administrator;Admin2** for above xml. the query is working fine..

But here, I expect the result only one entry **Administrator** not **Admin2**.. 
because Admin2 has both **Access:Allow** and **Access: Deny** values in two different ACEInformation node..

In that case, I have to exclude **Admin2** from result, even though it has the **Access:Allow**.

Can you any one give me the xquery for this case?

Answer (score 3):

```
with cte as (
    select
        A.X.value('(UserName/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as UserName,
        A.X.value('(Access/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as Access
    from myTable as T
        outer apply T.xmlColumn.nodes('/Security/Dacl/ACEInformation[Permission = "Delete"]') as A(X)
)
select *
from cte as c1
where
    c1.Access = 'Allow' and
    not exists (select * from cte as c2 where c2.UserName = c1.UserName and c2.Access = 'Deny')
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b7afc/2)</kbd>**

#### update

This one will give you desired result.

```
with cte as (
    select
        T.ID,
        A.X.value('(UserName/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as UserName,
        A.X.value('(Access/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as Access
    from myTable as T
        outer apply T.xmlColumn.nodes('/Security/Dacl/ACEInformation[Permission = "Delete"]') as A(X)
)
select
    T.ID,
    stuff(
        (
            select ',' + c1.UserName
            from cte as c1
            where
              c1.ID = T.ID and c1.Access = 'Allow' and
              not exists (select * from cte as c2 where c2.ID = T.ID and c2.UserName = c1.UserName and c2.Access = 'Deny')
            for xml path(''), type
        ).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)')
    ,1,1,'')
from myTable as T
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2e61e/11)</kbd>**

I think it's possible to do this with pure XQuery, try to add this later.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.. it is working fine ...it returns result as rows ..but my need is, I have to join all the username and get in single column like 'Administrator;TestUser;TestUser2'

Comment: do you need it in one row, or one row for each myTable row? Do you have identifier in myTable?

Comment: I need one row for each myTable row...Yes I have identifier (ID) in myTable ...I have to show results as two columns (ID, AllowedUsers) .. Allowedusers is the combined value of selected UserNames from xmlcolumn

Comment: It means I need to put CTE inside the select query.. is it possible?